# Multiple regression to extract the coefficients, intercept and R-Squared

Tags: excel, vba

Could anyone please tell me how to extract the coefficients, intercept and R-Squared using VBA from the table below?

```
X     y       z
1     2000    40000
2     2100    3433
3     2111    4333
4     2122    2133
5     3988    2311
6     1232    2311
7     1211    4322
1     2343    2121
2     2112    2222
3     2543    2111
4     3211    2321
5     2322    1114
6     2133    1223
7     3455    4698
```

Note (`X` and `y`) are the known variables and `z` the unknown. I have been able to do it in R but can't seem to replicate the idea with VBA.

(*Transferred from Comments*) This is the result of the same problem in R Coefficients:

```
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) (Intercept) -4949.5047 956.9503 -5.172 6.08e-06
KA$DaysMon -288.6500 223.8454 -1.290 0.204279
KA$DaysSat  837.1536 229.3117  3.651 0.000718
KA$DaysSun -797.0467 241.3208 -3.303 0.001961
KA$DaysThu -415.5882 227.5814 -1.826 0.074949
KA$DaysTue  158.6132 225.7859  0.702 0.486247
KA$DaysWed  125.3746 237.8353  0.527 0.600864
KA$P.Avail    1.4648   0.1623  9.025 2.19e-11
```

Comment: i want the coefficients if 1,2,3,4,5,6,7(data type is  a factor not integer) and  then coefficient of Y and then the intercept. actually the 1-7 values represent monday-sunday. i dont know if that helps

Comment: This is the result of the same problem in R Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -4949.5047   956.9503  -5.172 6.08e-06 ***
KA$DaysMon   -288.6500   223.8454  -1.290 0.204278    
KA$DaysSat    837.1536   229.3117   3.651 0.000718 ***
KA$DaysSun   -797.0467   241.3208  -3.303 0.001961 ** 
KA$DaysThu   -415.5882   227.5814  -1.826 0.074949 .  
KA$DaysTue    158.6132   225.7859   0.702 0.486247    
KA$DaysWed    125.3746   237.8353   0.527 0.600864    
KA$P.Avail      1.4648     0.1623   9.025 2.19e-11 **

Comment: Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -4949.5047   956.9503  -5.172 6.08e-06 ***
KA$DaysMon   -288.6500   223.8454  -1.290 0.204278    
KA$DaysSat    837.1536   229.3117   3.651 0.000718 ***
KA$DaysSun   -797.0467   241.3208  -3.303 0.001961 ** 
KA$DaysThu   -415.5882   227.5814  -1.826 0.074949 .  
KA$DaysTue    158.6132   225.7859   0.702 0.486247    
KA$DaysWed    125.3746   237.8353   0.527 0.600864    
KA$P.Avail      1.4648     0.1623   9.025 2.19e-11 **